# Set of upper bounds is finite for any finite subset

Tags: order-theory, graph-theory

Is there a term to describe a preordered set $P$ in which any finite subset $S \subset P$ has at most finitely many minimal upper bounds? The preordered sets I'm studying generally aren't join-semilattices. Apologies if this is well-known.

The principle example I'm looking at is the set of vertices in a directed graph, where we take $v \leq w$ to mean that there is a directed path from $w$ to $v$.

Comment: I don't know, as I am not an order theorist.  However, the terms 'compact' and 'algebraic' spring to mind; perhaps there is a paper out there which contains those terms as well as what you seek.  Gerhard "Somewhat Ignorant About Order Theory" Paseman, 2013.04.08

Comment: I think Gerhard is on the right track: this is a kind of weak compactness property. I would try *Continuous Lattices and Domains* by Gierz, Hofmann, Keimel, Lawson, Mislove, and Scott, but it's probably obscure even there.